# Access to distant PHP files with local PHP/JS files and keeping session alive

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, phpdesktop

For the purpose of a game, I have a server containing the database and PHP files handling requests which make changes to the database, and send through a pusher API (Pubnub) message to clients detailing the new state of the game (they receive it through JavaScript).

Since the game is a conversion of a web game in executable done with PHP Desktop, the clients can't access anymore to the server with ajax like I did before, (because the client is now detached from the web server) I need to call the distant PHP files BUT I also need to keep the session alive server side (The server handler check for the id of the game and the id of the player to verify that the requests are legals) and I don't want the client to be able to alter these data before sending.

Is there a way to do it through PHP or JavaScript since this is what the clients have as executable? Curl? Something else?

Comment: Try google: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+external+requests